# Recycleview children fit the screen height

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to have a 3*4 grid that will fit into any screen.

With the Recycleview grid the children views are only filling the width of the screen and not the height.

```
mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_plan_grid);
mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 3);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

mAdapter = new TripPlanningGridAdapter(getApplicationContext());
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Is there a way making the child of the recyclerview have the height of 1/4 the screen height?

I know about another approach to use nested relative and linear layouts, I'd like to know if it can be done with RecyclerView as well.